# How to Avoid DivideByZeroException

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi i got this error `Attempted to divide by zero` when i tried to run below code in a grid-view.

How can i avoid this error by returning zero as result of division when the error occur without avoiding division by zero.

**Code**

```
protected void gridpandl_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < this.gridpandl.Rows.Count; index++)
        {
            string Purchase = GetPurchase(this.gridpandl.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text);
            string Sales = GetSales(this.gridpandl.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text);
            string Serivce = GetService(this.gridpandl.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text);
            decimal Profit = (Convert.ToDecimal(Sales) + Convert.ToDecimal(Serivce) - Convert.ToDecimal(Purchase));
            decimal Profitprcn = (Profit * 100) / Convert.ToDecimal(Purchase);
            this.gridpandl.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text = Purchase;
            this.gridpandl.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text = Sales;
            this.gridpandl.Rows[index].Cells[4].Text = Serivce;
            this.gridpandl.Rows[index].Cells[5].Text = Profit.ToString();
            this.gridpandl.Rows[index].Cells[6].Text = Math.Round(Profitprcn, 2).ToString();
        }

    }

    catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the [conditional operator (?:).](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Change the `Profitprcn` line to this:

```
decimal Profitprcn = Convert.ToDecimal(Purchase) ==0? 0 : (Profit * 100) / Convert.ToDecimal(Purchase);
```

Comment: Still needs the `try-catch` though since the conversion can result in an expection of type `FormatException` or `OverflowException`...

Comment: Yea. And if you put the try catch inside the loop, it will still display rows that don't have any errors.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen - Just because there can be an exception doesn't mean you should catch it. You should only catch exceptions that you can meaningfully handle and recover from.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Yes. And that's exactly what the OP wants.

Answer (score -5):

Something like this:

```
decimal purchasesVal = 0;
decimal Profit = 0;
decimal Profitprcn = 0;

string Purchase = GetPurchase(this.gridpandl.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text);
string Sales = GetSales(this.gridpandl.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text);
string Serivce = GetService(this.gridpandl.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Purchases) && Convert.ToDecimal(Purchase) > 0)
{
    purchasesVal = Convert.ToDecimal(Purchase);
    Profit = (Convert.ToDecimal(Sales) + Convert.ToDecimal(Serivce) - purchasesVal);
    Profitprcn = (Profit * 100) / purchasesVal;
}
```

Comment: This will still throw if Purchase is "0"